# format double with dollar value without rounding off

Tags: java, format, double

I have a double value 13.4567. I have to format it without rounding off.

Expected value should be $13.4567. how to achieve it?

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO: what have you tried so far? What language are you using? please follow the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: im using Java language, when ever i try to format it , its rounding off to 2 decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("$#0.0000");
System.out.println(formatter.format(13.4567));
```

or

```
System.out.println(String.format("$%.4f", 13.4567));
```